# How to implement email address change in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I need to implement an option for email address change in Firebase.

I would like to find which Firebase function to use. Here is my code:

```
handleResetPassword = () => {
const { email } = this.state
this.context.auth
  .sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
  .then(() => {
    console.warn('Email is sent')
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      type: 'success',
      header: 'Email is sent',
      errorMessage:
        'Please check your email in order to change the password',
      password: ''
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    const { message } = error
    const errorMessage = !email ? 'Please enter an email address' : message
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      type: 'error',
      header: 'Email is not sent',
      errorMessage: errorMessage
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to [Update A Users Email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address)

Answer (score 0):

Enable Email Link sign-in for your Firebase project
In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/Password provider. ...
In the same section, enable Email link (passwordless sign-in) sign-in method.
Click Save.